# How to make Yammer REST API Call to get authenticated user's profile information?

Tags: rest, yammer

I am trying to call Yammer REST API for getting authenticated user's information using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
     method: "GET",
    url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json",

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            alert(data);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr2, status2) {
        alert(xhr2.status);
    }
});
});
```

However, it is always going to error method. Can anyone guide me to proceed on this piece?

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the API any authentication information, so how does it know what user it's supposed to be pulling down? You should take a look at the [Javascript SDK.](http://developer.yammer.com/yammer-sdks/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Change url from "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json" to "users/current.json" solves the issue (it will be going to success method)